# Overwriting GetHashCode (Enum plus Integer comparison)

Tags: c#, gethashcode

I want to overwrite a `GetHashCode` method with following code:

```
public override int GetHashCode()
{
    var magicNumber1 = 5;
    var magicNumber2 = 3;

    return intType * magicNumber1 + 
          (int)enumType * magicNumber2;
}
```

Is this a proper way of returning `GetHashCode` when one value is *Integer* and second an *Enum*?

Comment: Yes, that should work fine. Any specific concerns?

Comment: What are the **ranges** of `intType` and `enumType`, please?

Comment: Why these magic numbers? Use prime numbers like here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/263416/284240

Comment: I am not experienced and I am not sure if using magic number is best solution. Also there is a risk of overflowing, isnt it?

Comment: 1 quick search of SO would provide many answers....

Comment: As for the enum part of your question, yes, that's fine. The rest of the implementation can be found in the duplicate question.

Comment: Dmitry, it should not be more than 100

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, you current implementation is quite OK, but you can be *better off* if `intType` and `enumType` are of *small range*.
Suppose, `intType` (allmost always) is in the `[0..1000000]` and `enumType` is in the `[0..10]` range then

```
   public override int GetHashCode() {
      return unchecked(intType * 10 + (int)enumType);
   }
```

will be a *better choice*: many hash collisions that a present in your current code are not such in the code above. For instance

```
   intType | enumType | old hash | suggested
   -----------------------------------------
         0          5         15           5
         3          0         15          30
```

**Edit**: In your case (please, see comments)

> it should not be *more than 100*

assuming that you don't have *negative values*, you can try

```
   public override int GetHashCode() {
     // * 128 == << 7 may be faster than * 100 at some systems 
     return unchecked(intType * 128 + (int)enumType);
   }
```

and expect to have no collisions at all